# Communication with GARMIN through WEB

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, socket, location-services

I am developing a WEB based GPS system and one of its functionalities is to be able to send messages and routes to GARMIN devices.

I have never been using sockets before, and for some (obvious) reason, I don't feel ready to submit my code before being reviewed by more experienced users.

If some of you have the time to check it, here it is:

```
//This is an inner class - that is why it is private
private class MessageReceiver implements Runnable
{
      private Thread clientSocketListener = null;

      private Socket clientSocket = null;
      private Socket currentSocket = null;

      private ServerSocket mReceiverSocket = null;     

      private DataInputStream in = null;

      boolean shutDownServer = false;
      boolean stopLoop = false;


      public MessageReceiver()
      {
        try 
        {
            if(mReceiverSocket == null)  { mReceiverSocket = new ServerSocket(12346); }
            System.out.println("mReceiverSocket initialized");
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
      }


     /**
     * Listens for clients...
     */
    private void initConnection()
    {
        clientSocketListener = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {

            private boolean loopStatus = true;

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                    while(loopStatus)
                    {
                            try {Thread.sleep(200);} 
                            catch (InterruptedException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}


                            try
                            {   
                                clientSocket = mReceiverSocket.accept();

                                if(currentSocket != null) { currentSocket.close(); }

                                currentSocket = clientSocket;
                                System.out.println("new clientSocket accepted");                            
                            }
                            catch(SocketException e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("SocketException initConnection() ");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch(IOException e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Exception initConnection()");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                if(shutDownServer)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Breaking while looop for client listening");
                                    loopStatus = false;
                                }
                            }                                  
                    }
            }

        });

        clientSocketListener.setPriority(3);
        clientSocketListener.start();

    }


    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        this.initConnection();
        System.out.println("After calling initConncetion()");

        byte currentByte = 0;
        byte previousByte = 0;

        boolean firstRun = true;

        LinkedList<Byte> inputDataArray = new LinkedList<Byte>();

        while(stopLoop == false)
        {
            try 
            {                    
                if(currentSocket != null)
                {
                    in = new DataInputStream(currentSocket.getInputStream());

                    System.out.println("After checking if currentSocket is null");


                    int nextByte;
                    while((nextByte = this.in.read()) != -1)
                    {
                        if(firstRun)
                        {
                            firstRun = false;
                            previousByte = (byte) nextByte; //in.readByte();

                            if(previousByte == (byte) 0xa5) inputDataArray.add(previousByte);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentByte = (byte) nextByte; //in.readByte();

                            if(previousByte == 21 && currentByte == 22)
                            {
                                inputDataArray.clear();
                                System.out.println("Na4alo...");
                            }
                            else if(previousByte == 23 && currentByte == 24)
                            {
                                //Do something here...

                                if(type.equals(GarminMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE_GARMIN_TEXT))
                                {
                                    //Do what is supposed to do...
                                }
                                else if(type.equals(GarminMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE_GARMIN_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT))
                                {
                                    //Do what is supposed to do...    
                                }
                                else if(type.equals(GarminMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE_SYNCHRONIZE_POINT_ACCNOWELDGEMENT))
                                {
                                     //Do what is supposed to do...    
                                }
                                else if(type.equals(GarminMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE_ETA_ACCNOWELDGEMENT))
                                {
                                      //Do what is supposed to do... 
                                }

                                inputDataArray.clear();
                                firstRun = true;

                                System.out.println("Krai!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                inputDataArray.add(currentByte);
                                previousByte = currentByte;



                                if(inputDataArray.size() == 5)
                                {
                                    boolean flag = true;
                                    for(int i=0; i<inputDataArray.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        byte a = inputDataArray.get(i);     //System.out.println("data: " + a);
                                        if(a != (byte) 0xa5)
                                        {
                                            flag = false;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if(flag == true)
                                    {
                                        //System.out.println("Handshake message received");
                                        inputDataArray.clear();
                                        firstRun = true;

                                        byte handShakeMessage[] = new byte[]{(byte) 0xa6,(byte) 0xa6,(byte) 0xa6,(byte) 0xa6,(byte) 0xa6};

                                        try
                                        {
                                            MessageService.this.messageSender.out.write(handShakeMessage);
                                            MessageService.this.messageSender.out.flush();
                                        }
                                        catch (IOException ex) 
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("IOException: Connection has been lost and the handshake message was not sent!");
                                            if(MessageService.this.messageSender.out != null)
                                            {
                                                try {MessageService.this.messageSender.out.close();} 
                                                catch (IOException e) {} 
                                                finally{MessageService.this.messageSender.out = null;}
                                            }

                                            if(MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket != null)
                                            {
                                                try {MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket.close();} 
                                                catch (IOException e) {} 
                                                finally{MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket = null;} 
                                            }

                                            MessageService.this.messageSender.initConnection();
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("Exception: Connection has been lost and the handshake message was not sent!");
                                            if(MessageService.this.messageSender.out != null)
                                            {
                                                try {MessageService.this.messageSender.out.close();} 
                                                catch (IOException e) {} 
                                                finally{MessageService.this.messageSender.out = null;}
                                            }

                                            if(MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket != null)
                                            {
                                                try {MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket.close();} 
                                                catch (IOException e) {} 
                                                finally{MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket = null;} 
                                            }

                                            MessageService.this.messageSender.initConnection();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }             
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("IOException inside while loop of run method of thread message receiver");

                inputDataArray.clear();
                this.closeInputStream();
                this.closeSocket();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Exception");

                inputDataArray.clear();
                this.closeInputStream();
                this.closeSocket();
            }
            finally
            {
                try {Thread.sleep(200);} 
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            }


        } //end of while(true)

        System.out.println("Outside while loop");
        //shutDownServer = true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > ```
   > private ServerSocket mReceiverSocket = null;
   > ...
   > public MessageReceiver()
   > {
   >     try 
   >     {
   >         if(mReceiverSocket == null)  { mReceiverSocket = new ServerSocket(12346); }
   >         System.out.println("mReceiverSocket initialized");
   >     } 
   >     catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
   > }
   > ```

   The if condition inside the constructor is never `false`. It could be simply the following:

   > ```
   > private ServerSocket mReceiverSocket;
   > ...
   > public MessageReceiver() {
   >     try {
   >         mReceiverSocket = new ServerSocket(12346);
   >         System.out.println("mReceiverSocket initialized");
   >     } catch (IOException ex) {
   >         ex.printStackTrace();
   >     }
   > }
   > ```
2. Allowing to create an object with an invalid state (when `receiverSocket` is `null`) does not look a good idea. You'll get a `NullPointerException` later, usually when it runs on another thread. It's harder to debug since the stacktrace will not contain any clue where was the `MessageReceiver` created. So, instead of `printStackTrace` throw an exception immediately. (*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.)
3. > ```
   > boolean shutDownServer = false;
   > boolean stopLoop = false;
   > ```

   I guess it's not thread-safe. Access to the fields above should be synchronized, otherwise not all thread will see that their values are changed.

   > [...] synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

   Source: *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*

   > Unless synchronization is used every time a variable is accessed,
   >   it is possible to see a stale value for that variable. Worse, 
   >   staleness is not all-or-nothing: a thread can see an up-to-date
   >   value of one variable but a stale value of another variable that
   >   was written first.

   Source: *Java Concurrency in Practice*, *3.1.1. Stale Data*

   Consider using `AtomicBoolean`s.
4. Fourteen level of indentation is hard to read (you need to scroll horizontally), you should extract out some methods and classes to fulfil the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Having small classes and methods means that you don't have to understand the whole program when maintaining it later to modify just a small part of it which is easier and requires less work.

   > The first rule of functions is that they should be small. 
   >   The second rule of functions is that
   >   they should be smaller than that.

   Source: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Chapter 3: Functions*
5. In the `run` method a simple [guard clause](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) could save you an indentation level.

   > ```
   > while(stopLoop == false)
   > {
   >     try 
   >     {                    
   >         if(currentSocket != null)
   >         {
   >             ...
   >         }
   >     }
   >     ...
   > }
   > ```

   would become

   ```
   while (stopLoop == false) {
       try {
           if (currentSocket == null) {
               continue;
           }
           ...
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
6. The following try-catch (with every catch blocks) could have a separate method too:

   > ```
   > byte handShakeMessage[] = new byte[] { (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6 };
   >
   > try {
   >     MessageService.this.messageSender.out.write(handShakeMessage);
   >     MessageService.this.messageSender.out.flush();
   > } catch (IOException ex) {
   >     ...
   > }
   > ```
7. The content of the two `catch` blocks above is exactly the same, you can move that logic to a separate method too:

   ```
   private void closeAndReconnect() {
       if (MessageService.this.messageSender.out != null) {
           try {
               MessageService.this.messageSender.out.close();
           } finally {
               MessageService.this.messageSender.out = null;
           }
       }

       if (MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket != null) {
           try {
               MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
           } finally {
               MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket = null;
           }
       }

       MessageService.this.messageSender.initConnection();
   }
   ```

   Then it gets being readable, although a good name is still missing:

   ```
   private void extracted() {
       byte handShakeMessage[] = new byte[] { (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xa6 };

       try {
           MessageService.this.messageSender.out.write(handShakeMessage);
           MessageService.this.messageSender.out.flush();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           System.out.println("IOException: Connection has been lost and the handshake message was not sent!");
           closeAndReconnect();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Exception: Connection has been lost and the handshake message was not sent!");
           closeAndReconnect();
       }
   }
   ```
8. If both `messageSender.out` and `messageSender.mSenderSocket` implements `Closeable` you could create a `closeQuietly` method for them:

   ```
   private void closeQuietly(final Closeable closeable) {
       if (closeable == null) {
           return;
       }
       try {
           closeable.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
    private void closeAndReconnect() {
       try {
           closeQuietly(MessageService.this.messageSender.out);
           closeQuietly(MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket);
       } finally {
           MessageService.this.messageSender.out = null;
           MessageService.this.messageSender.mSenderSocket = null;
       }

       MessageService.this.messageSender.initConnection();
   }
   ```

   Anyway, it's usually not a good idea to swallow exceptions. You should at least log them, it could help with "doesn't work" bugs where there is no other clue what has happened.
9. Numbers like, `0xa5`, `21`, `24` are magic numbers. Using a named constants would help readers/maintainers because named constants could express the purpose of value, they would reveal the intent, what the original author wanted to achieve with the number.
10. > ```
    > boolean shutDownServer = false;
    > ```

    `shutdown` is one word, I'd write it with lowercase `d`.
11. > ```
    > private ServerSocket mReceiverSocket = null;
    > ```

    The `m` prefix is rather unnecessary.
12. > ```
    > LinkedList<Byte> inputDataArray = new LinkedList<Byte>();
    > ```

    `LinkedList<...>` reference types should be simply `List<...>`. See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
13. > ```
    > boolean flag = true;
    > ```

    I more descriptive name would help readers, since every `boolean` is a flag it doesn't say too much.

Comment: 10x. It's just amazing how well you explain stuff. I have to post questions more often here